# Java MongoDB driver can't parse query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, hibernate-ogm

I'm developing project with hibernate-ogm 5 with mongodb 3. But some query can not parsed. But I tested this query on shell. It works. What's wrong with this query?

```
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
db.Tree.update({'_id':2},{'$inc':{'totalUserCount':NumberInt(-1)}},{})
^
com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:230)
com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:155)
com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:92)
com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:73)
org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.query.parsing.nativequery.impl.MongoDBQueryDescriptorBuilder.build(MongoDBQueryDescriptorBuilder.java:71)
```

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried running the query without the `NumberInt()` wrapper `db.Tree.update({'_id':2},{'$inc':{'totalUserCount': -1}},{})`?

Comment: @chridam if I remove NumberInt() wrapper MongoDB will change datatype to double. I don't want this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, the parsing issue will be fixed in the next release of OGM.

Note that it will support NumberLong but not NumberInt as NumberInt is not supported by the MongoDB Java Driver: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2185 .

Answer (score 1):

The use of functions like `NumberInt` is not supported at the moment.

I've created an issue for it: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/OGM-1027